# Financial Corpus

Tags: data-request, finance, corpora, stock

I'll be delving into text mining applications for my master thesis and I need data for it. Ideally, I would need a corpora of texts/news articles from some single (or multiple) credible and authoritative source covering financial markets/economy and the like, spanning a time period as long as possible.

Does anyone know of datasets/corporas that would suit my requirements?
Any other possibilities/ideas to construct one such dataset using open resources?

I know this question has been already asked but the answers that were posted are not longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

[Reuters Financial Dataset as a structured DataFrame](https://github.com/Kriyszig/financial-news-data)

[Reuters Financial Dataset](https://github.com/Danbo3004/financial-news-dataset) is a large collection of Financial News Article scraped from Reuters website. Originally used for the paper [Using Structured Events to Predict Stock Price Movement:An Empirical Investigation - Ding et al.(2014)](http://emnlp2014.org/papers/pdf/EMNLP2014148.pdf) this set of unstructured data is a powerful warehouse of historic Financial Data. This script provides a way of arranging the huge corpus of information into a Pandas' efficient data structure DataFrame

Originally, this repository consisted of badly written Python script which was monolitic and cryptic. This refactor breaks the code down into smaller functions and comes equipped with a function to create the DataFrame.